# how to set ES_NOHIDESEL

Tags: c, winapi, window, styles

is there really NO way to set ES_NOHIDESEL at runtime?

i searched a lot, but nothing worked.

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hEdit, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(hEdit, GWL_STYLE, style | ES_NUMBER | ES_NOHIDESEL);
SetWindowPos(hEdit, HWND_TOPMOST, 100, 100, 666, 666, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

while ES_NUMBER is added to the style as expected, ES_NOHIDESEL is always ignored.

i kow it should be set at window creation. but i am trying to improve an existing project. and i already added ES_NOHIDESEL to every CreateWindow(Ex) in the code. this did not change anything, ES_NOHIDESEL is not set, selection disappears if the dialog loses focus.

i need ES_NOHIDESEL because i want to use FindText(), which it seems only works if ES_NOHIDESEL is set.

```
case WM_CREATE:
    hEdit = CreateWindow (("EDIT"), "this is just some test",
                 WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_NOHIDESEL,
                 0, 0, 0, 0,  hwnd, (HMENU)100, hInst, NULL) ;
    return 0;
```

^^ this works

```
case WM_CREATE:
    hEdit = CreateWindow (("EDIT"), "this is just some test",
                 WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE,
                 0, 0, 0, 0,  hwnd, (HMENU)100, hInst, NULL) ;

                 LONG style = GetWindowLong(hEdit, GWL_STYLE);
                 SetWindowLongPtr(hEdit, GWL_STYLE, style | ES_NUMBER | ES_NOHIDESEL);     
                 SetWindowPos(hEdit, HWND_TOPMOST, 100, 100, 666, 666, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    return 0;
```

^^ this does not what i expect. ES_NUMBER is added, ES_NOHIDESEL not.

Comment: "*i already added ES_NOHIDESEL to every CreateWindow(Ex) in the code. with no luck*" - meaning what, exactly? Luck with what? "*i need ES_NOHIDESEL because i want to use FindText()*" - what does `FindText()` have to do with this? That is a completely separate dialog, not related to Edit controls. An Edit control having/not having `ES_NOHIDESEL` has no effect on how `FindText()` works.  So, please elaborate with more details about your actual issues. Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the actual problem?

Comment: of course FindText() itsel works. but what's the point if it doesn't show the selection (found text)? as soon as the search dialog appears, there is no selection shown in my edit control anymore. so i can properly set the selection using EM_SETSEL, but it cannot be seen.

Comment: Try using a [RichEdit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/rich-edit-controls) instead, sending it an [`EM_SETOPTIONS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setoptions) message to enable the `ECO_NOHIDESEL` option, and then use [`EM_FINDTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-findtext) and [`EM_EXSETSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-exsetsel) messages.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: ok, i managed to make it work. and it was very easy after all. all i had to do is add ES_NOHIDESEL to the res.rc file. and also define it in a file called rescommon.h (included in res.rc). so this is SOLVED.

Comment: That doesn't sound plausible. An .rc file gets compiled into a binary representation that the system parses and feeds into `CreateWindow` calls at runtime. If adding the `ES_NOHIDESEL` style in the resource works then so does using it in a call to `CreateWindow`. The issue is something else. It's odd that your question never mentions a resource script. Could it be that you're creating two sets of controls, one from the resource script and another set through code?

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention this is an existing project i am playing with. using FindText() i wanted to add search in a "help text" which is a LOT of text in a simple text field. it's all in all >8000 files and and just the .c code is >50 megabytes. a clueless man like me doesn'treally know what's happening at prog launching.